# Raise JavaScript confirm Message from ASPX web form server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to raise a confirm message from asp webform code behind
then complete the code sequence according to the result of user confirmation
Like That:

```
void SaveData()
  {
      bool IsAvaliable = Validate();
      if(IsAvaliable)
            //Raise JavaScript Confirm Message 
     if(confirm == true)
     {
         save ();
     }
     else
        return;
     //
  }
```

How Can do This as the confirm message appears after server side code has finished ?!

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the server and the client.  You can't do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this stack, but is there any reason you can't trigger `SaveData()` on hitting the confirm button, and have everything that leads to that confirmation dialog appearing handled on the front end?  Everything up to pressing the confirmation button should be purely front-end flow that you're trying to involve back-end coordination on.

Answer (score 0):

A server-side operation (ASPX Web Forms) can't be paused to let a client-side operation (JavaScript in a web page) happen. Each occurs separately from the other (server-side first, then client-side result of server-side processing).

What you'll need to do is break your processing up into 2 stages:

1. The first web form will render a page that includes a **client-side** (JavaScript) `confirm()` dialog.
2. Depending on what the user selects, the JavaScript will then make a call to the appropriate next ASPX web form and that web form will then proceed as needed.